# Upper left icon doesn't change once window is made

Tags: c++, winapi, icons

I'm trying to add support to easily change a window's icon once it is made. To do this I use

```
SetClassLongPtr (hwnd, GCLP_HICONSM, (LONG)(HICON)LoadImage (NULL, path, IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, LR_LOADFROMFILE));
```

However, this changes the icon on the taskbar, but not the upper left corner. Large icon works normally on the alt-tab menu. Any ideas?

**Edit**
While the suggestion worked, I've had some problems using the same on a 64-bit Windows 7 PC (the other was 32-bit Windows XP). I remade the icon files to no avail. I was getting an error for an invalid handle after the call to `LoadImage()` for the large icon, but not the small. Loading the small icon first makes both work. Loading the large first sets the small and large icons to the large icon, but gives the error.

Here's the function. It's part of a wrapper, so I hope the explanations are good enough. Ignore it belonging to WinClass. I'm changing it to the class for normal windows once everything works.

```
//hwin = HWND, con = const
bool WinClass::setIcon (con hwin hwnd, con string & icon, con string & iconLarge)
{
    //load large icon
    HICON large = (HICON)LoadImage (null, iconLarge.c_str(), IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, LR_LOADFROMFILE); 

    //if GetLastError() is not 0, give details and return false
    //this one contains the invalid handle
    errorRet(); 

    //message box with confirmation and value of HICON
    //itos = integer to string
    msg (((string)"LoadImage() Succeeded! Icon handle has value ") += itos (*((int *)large)));

    //tell window to change its icon (or die)
    SendMessage (hwnd, WM_SETICON, (WPARAM)ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)large);

    errorRet();
    msg ("SendMessage() Succeeded!");
    _hIcon = (HICON)SendMessage (hwnd, WM_GETICON, (WPARAM)ICON_BIG, 0);
    errorRet();
    msg ("SendMessage() Succeeded!");

    //repeat for small icon
    HICON sm = (HICON)LoadImage (null, icon.c_str(), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    errorRet();
    msg ("LoadImage() Succeeded!");
    SendMessage (hwnd, WM_SETICON, (WPARAM)ICON_SMALL, (LPARAM)sm);
    errorRet();
    msg ("SendMessage() Succeeded!");
    _hIconSm = (HICON)SendMessage (hwnd, WM_GETICON, (WPARAM)ICON_SMALL, 0);
    errorRet();
    msg ("SendMessage() Succeeded!");

    return true;
}
```

Note: If I comment out the error-checking so that the whole function is executed, I end up with the upper-left icon right, the taskbar icon wrong and the alt-tab icon right.

**Edit 2**
Now if I do the small icon first and the big one after, the taskbar icon is wrong, but it gives no errors. If I make a message box after `SendMessage() set`ing the small icon, everything is normal. How do I even begin to explain one message box making it work?

Comment: Try sending the window a WM_NCPAINT message. Probably won't make a difference but it's worth a shot.

Comment: You definitely ought to consider sending WM_SETICON first.

Comment: Modifying the class is not the way to do this. Use `WM_SETICON`.

Comment: Alright. I was in a hurry when I asked this, sorry for that. I tried WM_NCPAINT, no luck. I used WM_SETICON and had an annoying problem with using a variable named "small", but it worked once I got that straightened out :)  Should I be using messages to set all of the `SetClassLongPtr` things, or just some, and if so, which ones besides icons?